# Display image from URL, Swift 4.2

Tags: ios, json, swift, nsdictionary

I am a fairly decent Objective C developer, and I am now learning Swift (of which I am finding quite difficult, not only because of new concepts, such as optionals, but also because Swift is continually evolving, and much of the available tutorials are severely outdated).

Currently I am trying parse a JSON from a url into an NSDictionary and then use one of its value to display an image (which is also a url). Something like this:

---

URL -> NSDictionary -> init UIImage from url -> display UIImage in UIImageView

---

This is quite easy in Objective C (and there may even be a shorter answer):

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=DEMO_KEY"];
NSData *apodData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSDictionary *apodDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:apodData options:0 error:nil];
```

The above code snippet gives me back a standard NSDictionary, in which I can refer to the "url" key to get the address of the image I want to display:

---

"url" : "https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/1811/hillpan_apollo15_4000.jpg"

---

This I then convert into a UIImage and give it to a UIImageView:

```
NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString: [apodDict objectForKey:@"url"]];
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
UIImage *apodImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

UIImageView *apodView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: apodImage];
```

Now, I am basically trying to replicate the above Objective C code in Swift but continuously run into walls. I have tried several tutorials (one of which actually did the exact same thing: display a NASA image), as well as find a few stack overflow answers but none could help because they are either outdated or they do things differently than what I need.

So, I would like to ask the community to provide the Swift 4 code for the these problems:

```
1. Convert data from url into a Dictionary
2. Use key:value pair from dict to get url to display an image
```

If it is not too much already, I would also like to ask for detailed descriptions alongside the code because I would like the answer to be the one comprehensive "tutorial" for this task that I believe is currently not available anywhere.

Thank you!

Comment: In Swift you should use `URL`, not `NSURL`. Use `Data`, not `NSData`. Use a Swift dictionary, not `NSDictionary`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all I'm pretty sure that in half a year you will find Objective-C very complicated and difficult.

Second of all even your ObjC code is discouraged. Don't load data from a remote URL with synchronous `Data(contentsOf` method. Regardless of the language use an asynchronous way like `(NS)URLSession`.

And don't use Foundation collection types `NSArray` and `NSDictionary` in Swift. Basically don't use `NS...` classes at all if there is a native Swift counterpart.

In Swift 4 you can easily decode the JSON with the `Decodable` protocol directly into a (Swift) struct,
the URL string can be even decoded as `URL`.

Create a struct

```
struct Item: Decodable {
    // let copyright, date, explanation: String
    // let hdurl: String
    // let mediaType, serviceVersion, title: String
    let url: URL
}
```

Uncomment the lines if you need more than the URL.

And load the data with two data tasks.

```
let url = URL(string: "https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=DEMO_KEY")! 

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, error) in
    if let error = error { print(error); return }
    do {
       let decoder = JSONDecoder()
       // this line is only needed if all JSON keys are decoded
       decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
       let result = try decoder.decode(Item.self, from: data!)
       let imageTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: result.url) { (imageData, _, imageError) in
           if let imageError = imageError { print(imageError); return }
           DispatchQueue.main.async {
               let apodImage = UIImage(data: imageData!)
               let apodView = UIImageView(image: apodImage)
               // do something with the image view
           }
       }
       imageTask.resume()
   } catch { print(error) }
}
task.resume()
```

Comment: Vadian, you seem to know what you're doing, thank you for your answer! However, I would like to ask you for a few modifications before I accept it:

1. Would you mind modifying your main function to just return an NSDictionary object (because of clean coding, so every function does only one task).

2. Would you mind commenting your code, so I know what each line does and why/how? This is important to understand your answer and not simply copy/paste. I know this is a lot, but I think it is needed to fill the void that is the current lack of tutorials for this task.

Comment: As I said, don't use `NSDictionary` in Swift. A struct is *swiftier*, safer and more efficient. The asynchronous task doesn't *return* anything so you would need a (or two) completion handler. There are countless questions here on SO about `URLSession` and completion handlers.

Comment: Sorry, not NSDictionary, struct. You are right! But the more important thing is that I still do not understand your code. :( At this moment, all I can do is copy and paste it, which is not what I'm looking for; I want to understand what I am doing. I also think it is important to adhere to clean coding rules and let functions handle specific tasks, such as decoding a JSON into a language compatible data object. This later would also help me understand your solution better because it would be broken down to smaller tasks.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this extension

```
extension UIImage {

    public static func loadFrom(url: URL, completion: @escaping (_ image: UIImage?) -> ()) {
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(UIImage(data: data))
                }
            } else {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(nil)
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Using

```
guard let url = URL(string: "http://myImage.com/image.png") else { return }

UIImage.loadFrom(url: url) { image in
    self.photo.image = image
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since image loading is a trivial and at the same time task which could be implemented in many different ways, I would recommend you to not "reinvent the wheel" and have a look to an image loading library such as **[Nuke](https://github.com/kean/Nuke)**, since it already covers most of the cases you might need during your development process.

It allows you to load and show image asynchronously into your view, using simple api:

```
Nuke.loadImage(with: url, into: imageView)
```

And also if you need - to specify *how* image should be loaded and presented:

```
let options = ImageLoadingOptions(
placeholder: UIImage(named: "placeholder"),
failureImage: UIImage(named: "failure_image"),
contentModes: .init(
    success: .scaleAspectFill,
    failure: .center,
    placeholder: .center
)
)
Nuke.loadImage(with: url, options: options, into: imageView)
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an UIIimageView Extension and the following code

```
extension UIImageView {
public func imageFromServerURL(urlString: String) {
    self.image = nil
    let urlStringNew = urlString.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "%20")
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: NSURL(string: urlStringNew)! as URL, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in

        if error != nil {
            print(error as Any)
            return
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
            let image = UIImage(data: data!)
            self.image = image
        })

    }).resume()
}}
```

and

```
self.UploadedImageView.imageFromServerURL(urlString: imageURLStirng!)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have just extended on vadian's answer, separated some concerns to clearly understand the basics. His answer should suffice.

First, you have to build your structure. This will represent the JSON structure you retrieved from the webservice.

```
struct Item: Codable {
    let url, hdurl : URL,
    let copyright, explanation, media_type, service_version, title : String
}
```

Then make you request methods. I usually create a separate file for it. Now, vadian mentioned about completion handlers. These are represented by escaping closures. Here, closure ()->  is passed on both functions and called having the decoded data as argument.

```
struct RequestCtrl {

    func fetchItem(completion: @escaping (Item?)->Void) {

         let url = URL(string: "https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=DEMO_KEY")!
         //URLSessionDataTask handles the req and returns the data which you will decode based on the Item structure we defined above.
         let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, _) in 
             let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
             if let data = data,
                let item = try? jsonDecoder.decode(Item.self, from: data){
                //jsonDecoder requires a type of our structure represented by .self and the data from the request.  
                completion(item)
             } else {
                 completion(nil)
             }
          }
         task.resume()
    }


    func fetchItemPhoto(usingURL url: URL, completion: @escaping (Data?)-> Void) {
         let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, _) in
            if let data = data { completion(data) } else { completion(nil) }
          }
         task.resume()
    }
}
```

Now in you ViewController, call your request and handle the execution of your closure.

```
  class ViewController: UIViewController {

      let requestCtrl = RequestCtrl()

      override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()

         requestCtrl.fetchItem { (fetchedItem) in
            guard let fetchedItem = fetchedItem else { return }
            self.getPhoto(with: fetchedItem)
         }

      }

      func getPhoto(with item: Item) {
           requestCtrl.fetchItemPhoto(usingURL: item.url) { (fetchedPhoto) in
                 guard let fetchedPhoto = fetchedPhoto else { return }
                 let photo = UIImage(data: fetchedPhoto)
                  //now you have a photo at your disposal 
           }
      }
  }
```

These are not the best of practices since I am also still learning, so by all means do some research on topics especially closures, ios concurrency and URLComponents on Apple's documentation :)

Answer (score 0):

**you need to convert url into string and data to add in imageview**

```
let imageURL:URL=URL(string: YourImageURL)!
let data=NSData(contentsOf: imageURL)
Yourimage.image=UIImage(data: data! as Data)
```

Answer (score 0):

First add the pod in Podfile 
pod 'Alamofire', 
pod 'AlamofireImage'
you can check this link for install pods => https://cocoapods.org/pods/AlamofireImage

// Use this function for load image from URL in imageview

```
imageView.af_setImage(
    withURL: url,
    placeholderImage: placeholderImage //its optional if you want to add placeholder
)
```

Check this link for method of alamofireImage
https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage/blob/master/Documentation/AlamofireImage%203.0%20Migration%20Guide.md

Answer (score 0):

Update for **Xcode 13.3** , **Swift 5**

To load the Image asynchronously from a URL string, use this extension:

```
extension UIImageView {

public func getImageFromURLString(imageURLString: String) {
    guard let imageURL = URL(string: imageURLString) else { return}
    Task {
        await requestImageFromURL(imageURL)
    }
}

private func requestImageFromURL(_ imageURL: URL) async{
    let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: imageURL)
    do {
        let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: urlRequest)
        
        if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse{
            if httpResponse.statusCode == 200{
                print("Fetched image successfully")
            }
        }
        // Loading the image here
        self.image = UIImage(data: data)
    } catch let error {
        print(error)
    }
}
}
```

Usage:

```
imageView.getImageFromURLString(imageURLString: "https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/1811/hillpan_apollo15_4000.jpg")
```